# Is it correct to say all erased types are non-initializable?

Tags: swift, type-erasure, initializer, anyobject

(By erased types I mean: (`Any`, `AnyHashable`, `AnyObject`), `protocol`, or root class `NSObject`).

I'm asking this question because in the code below I can't initialize `something` to `AnyObject`. I get error:

> cannot invoke initializer for type 'AnyObject?' with no arguments

and I'm looking for a proper workAround. I don't think the right choice is to initialize `something` in each statement...

```
func returnObject() -> AnyObject{

    var something = AnyObject()

    if x == someProperty{
        something = y
    }
    else if x == anotherProperty{
        something = z
    }else{
        something = t
    }
    return something   

}
```

Comment: `var something: AnyObject?` or `let something: AnyObject` and make sure you initialize it in every case

Comment: Protocols can't be initialized. Because they could be one of any number of classes, with different under-the-hood properties and functions. You can see from the Swift documentation that NSObject (a class) and AnyHashable (a struct) can in fact be initialized.

Comment: `AnyHashable` is a very different thing to `Any` or `AnyObject` – it's a type-erased wrapper rather than an protocol.

Comment: @LeoDabus Hah! didn't know I can use `:` / declarations inside a function. I thought I should always just `=` / assign...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What would you expect the initialization to do? What does it matter anyway, if you plan to immediately overwrite `something` with `y`, `z` or `t`?

```
func returnObject() -> AnyObject {

    let something: AnyObject

    if x == someProperty{
        something = y
    }
    else if x == anotherProperty{
        something = z
    }
    else{
        something = t
    }
    return something   

}
```

However, it's more succinct to use a `switch`:

```
func returnObject() -> AnyObject {
    let something: AnyObject

    switch x {
        case someProperty:    something = y
        case anotherProperty: something = z
        default:              something = t
    }

    return something
}
```

And if you're just returning `something`, you can just inline it:

```
func returnObject() -> AnyObject {
    switch x {
        case someProperty:    return y
        case anotherProperty: return z
        default:              return t
    }
}
```

Comment: @LeoDabus Fixed

Comment: something never changed why don't you use let?

Comment: @LeoDabus Also fixed

Comment: Can you also address this: "is it correct to say all erased types are non-initializable?"

Comment: @Honey `erased types` is not a vigorously defined term, so the question is meaningless

Comment: `Any`, `AnyObject` and all protocols aren't directly initializable. `AnyHashable` is obviously initializable (how else would you use it?) , and `NSObject` is as well.

Comment: "`AnyHashable` is obviously initializable " <-- like what?

Comment: @Honey e.g. `AnyHashable("abc")`

Comment: My point was that you can't do `AnyObject()` because it won't make any sense, initializing to an unknown type with an unknown value, it only makes to keep it to `nil` —which is known.

Comment: @Honey yep. And that's the case with any protocol (AnyObject and Any are protocols)